# How to create this coloured pencil effect?

Tags: inkscape, effects

How can I recreate this coloured pencil effect with Inkscape? The original image is just flat colours with a slight gradient on the background. I uploaded it to PhotoMania and used their coloured pencil effect which produced this output:

[image: sample_image]

The export from PhotoMania is very low resolution so I'm trying to recreate the effect in Inkscape. I've played around with all the filter options, but I can't find anything that's even close.

The main issue is the way the lines extend from the cupcakes and the clouds. I can get the edge detection using a convolution filter, but I can't think of any way to have the lines extend like this.

Inkscape doesn't seem to have a transform option for custom filters, but even if it did that would only allow simple horizontal/vertical transforms, which wouldn't create this "extended line" effect.

Comment: These type of effects are typical of raster image tools (like PhotoMania, GIMP, etc.). Inkscape is a vector image editor.

Comment: Good point. However, I'd still like to be able to create it myself, even if I do have to do it with an exported raster image.

Answer (score 5):

You could certainly draw the graphics in Inkscape, but the rest are almost certainly raster effects, which Inkscape isn't really designed for. Although it does have some limited effects, there's nothing like that.

You could open the SVG of the graphics (made in Inkscape) in GIMP.

Next, create a filled blue layer on the bottom, then a white filled layer on top of that.

Apply the HSV Noise filter to the white layer.

Then scale the noise layer up to make it coarser. Then do a motion blur on that layer, and set the layer blending mode to Burn.

If you install the G'MIC plugin for GIMP, there's a filter for a black and white Sketch effect which you could apply to a duplicate of the SVG layer, then set that layer's mode to Burn. It's not exactly the same, but close.

Example:

[image]